# fadeOut() effect works fine on firefox, but not on chrome

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-chrome

I have a list of items with a standard CRUD next to each. I added the js function below for items to fade when deleting.

The effect works perfect on Firefox, but on Chrome it doesn't. It does delete the item, but doesn't show the effect.

Can anyone help? What is going on?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.delete_phone').bind('ajax:success', function() {  
        $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();  
    });
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You cannot seem to fade out `<tr>`s: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944110/jquery-fadeout-not-working-with-table-rows.

Answer (score 0):

use `$(document).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`

Comment: for some reason the effect doesn't work on Firefox neither if I change to $(document).load()