# jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut issue in Chrome, but works in firefox

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, carousel

Any reason why the arrows on this carousel fade out in firefox but not chrome?
[Please find the link](http://we-are-lucky.com/stage/666/The-Lucky/Ben/index9.php)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{    
    $("div.slider-wrap").hover(
      function () {
        $("div.stripNavL").fadeIn('slow');
        $("div.stripNavR").fadeIn('slow');
      }, 
      function () {
        $("div.stripNavL").fadeOut('slow');
        $("div.stripNavR").fadeOut('slow');
      }
    );
});​
```

You will notice the arrows still don't show up in Chrome, and in FF, the whole carousel doesn't work properly

as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063264/fadeout-effect-works-fine-on-firefox-but-not-on-chrome) I change document ready to load, but still no luck.

Comment: In Chrome 13 I get a syntax error - invalid token, line 41 in index9.php. Although I can't see why that would be happening. Sidenote - you may want to use jQuery min instead of jQuery pack.

Comment: @Sameera seriously you need to smush down image sizes, one of them is `1.2 mb` also it would be best if you show small images first on clicking ajax load the big ones. As for the problem i don't experience it on my machine

Comment: @mrtsherman: me neither. Really strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange. In both Fx and Chrome, there's a 404 in trying to fetch svwloader.gif at the path specified.

The GIF loading is done within the Coda slider JS. Firefox forgives the missing file, but Chrome stops the script from executing.

Comment: Changes done, thanks alot its based on what was you mentioned.